# Prevent two Buttons from being pressed at the same time

Tags: android, android-button

I have created a small game where the first user to click the button after a timer runs out wins the game. The problem occurs when both players click the button at the same time. If this happens, "displayWinner" gets called twice and two "winner" activities get called. How can I prevent this?

Here is my code:

```
 player1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.p1incrementer);
 player2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.p2incrementer);

 player1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                player1.setEnabled(false);
                player2.setEnabled(false);
                p1win=true;
                displayWinner();
            }
        });
 player2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                player1.setEnabled(false);
                player2.setEnabled(false);
                p1win=false;
                displayWinner();
            }
        });

public void displayWinner()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, WinnerActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("winner", p1win);
    this.finish(); 
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: synchronize displayWinner() & have a boolean field which shows if displayWinner has been called yet or not?

Comment: try creating 1 listener for both buttons and then use a switch() statement

Comment: @panini using a simple boolean did the trick! I can't believe I didn't think of that before... :)